# Writing a script from google calender

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-calendar-api

First off i am very new to coding, I know pretty much next to nothing, but I'd love to learn, I was asked by a friend to help him link his google calendar to Excel. So I did some searching and found that linking it to google spreadsheet is easier from there I can link it to Excel. So below i have the current script I'm using. I want to add a little more format though.
Let's say I make an event in google calendar and I add a description, I want it to detect lines from the description to add in new columns [Screenshot of Google Spreadsheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j1jcG.png). The comment in one column and the date in another column. See example below. Is this at all possible?

[Screen shoot of the Google Calendar event](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mgOG0.png)

July 27 (press enter)
Dropped of 5 skids (press enter)
July 30 (press enter)
Picked up 5 skids

Here is my current script I am using please note i removed my actual calendar ID.

```
function listEvents() {

  var today = new Date();
  var Calendar  =  CalendarApp.getCalendarById("my calender id");
  //var Calendar  =  CalendarApp.getDefaultCalendar();


  var events = Calendar.getEvents(today, new Date(2020,12,31));

  var eventarray = new Array();
  for (var i = 0; i<events.length; i++)
  {
    var line = new Array();
    line.push(events[i].getTitle());
    line.push(events[i].getStartTime());
    line.push(events[i].getEndTime());
    line.push(events[i].getDescription());
    eventarray.push(line);
  }

  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(2, 1, eventarray.length, eventarray[0].length).setValues(eventarray);
}​
```

Answer (score 0):

After using [getRange](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangerow-column) to determine the position of the cell, use [setValue(value)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setvaluevalue) to write to the cell.